# duplicate and change id more than once

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new at this forum, and not a pro at doing websites, but now I doing a job for a friend, I want to duplicate a div and change the id, and I know how to do so, but, I want to be able to change the id more than once, now the new id will be "bubbla1" and the next time I click at the button I want it to change to "bubbla2" and so on...  I post my html:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Ny Boll</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
var elmnt = document.getElementsByTagName("DIV") [2];
var cln = elmnt.cloneNode(true);
document.body.appendChild(cln);
cln.id = "bubbla1" ;
}
</script>
```

Comment: First of all, this is not a forum. This is a Q/A site for professional programmers . Read the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a counter to keep track of the number of divs you have added to the page, increment by one each time and appending the total to the id of the div, like so;

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Ny Boll</button>
<script>
  var counter = 1;
  function myFunction() {
    var elmnt = document.getElementsByTagName("DIV") [2];
    var cln = elmnt.cloneNode(true);
    document.body.appendChild(cln);
    cln.id = "bubbla" + counter ;
    counter++;
  }
</script>
```